# Are foundation models something fundamentally new? Is there a proper definition?

Tags: deep-learning, transfer-learning

Currently, one can hear more and more about "foundation models" but details of this are not  always clear. Also, I even have the impression, that sometimes people don't talk about exactly the same thing. Sometimes all of this feels a bit nebulous in the spirit of "*let's throw as much data as possible at as many GPUs as possible, and something useful and predictive will come out*". This clearly can be fun but in the worst case just produce a tremendous amount of CO2...

Therefore I am wondering if there exists a clear definition of what a foundation model is (or is not) and if you know of good examples that demonstrate the usefulness and novelties? Do you believe that this is something truly new or just a scaled-up version of what we are doing anyway so far?

Thanks in advance for sharing your insights!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A foundation model is any model that is trained on broad data (generally using self-supervision at scale) that can be adapted (e.g., fine-tuned) to a wide range of downstream tasks

from ["On the Opportunities and Risks of Foundation Models"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.07258) seems like a clear and reasonable definition.

["Unsupervised word sense disambiguation rivaling supervised methods"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.3115/981658.981684) from 1995 is considered self-supervised. Most researchers would not call that part new to foundation models.

The "can be adapted to a wide range of downstream tasks" also certainly pre-dates  modern "foundation models" e.g. ["Self-taught learning: transfer learning from unlabeled data"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1273496.1273592) from 2007.

So "is it something fundamentally / truly new"? Not really, but still very impressive.